# tensorflow warning - Found untraced functions such as lstm_cell_6_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses

Tags: tensorflow, warnings, lstm

I'm using tensorflow2.4, and new to tensorflow

Here's the code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics='mae')
model.summary()

save_weights_at = 'basic_lstm_model'
save_best = ModelCheckpoint(save_weights_at, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
                        save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='min',
                        period=1)
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=20,
         verbose=1, callbacks=[save_best], validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
         shuffle=True)
```

And in some epochs, got this warning:
[image]

Do you know why did I get this warning?

Comment: Have the same issue, also using LSTM layers. Did you get it solved?

Comment: not yet~ didn't impact output in my case though...

Comment: @Cherry Wu, I tried executing without `ModelCheckpoint` and it is not showing any warning. It seems this is an open issue in `TF 2.4` and it can be tracked [Saving model in TF 2.4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47479). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @TFer2! Yeah, in my case have to use `ModelCheckpoint`

Answer (score 20):

I think this warning can be safely ignored as you can find the same warning even in a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation) given by tensorflow. I often see this warning when saving custom models such as graph NNs. You should be good to go as long as you don't want to access those non-callable functions.

However, if you're annoyed by this big chunk of text, you can suppress this warning by adding the following at the top of the code.

```
import absl.logging
absl.logging.set_verbosity(absl.logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: what if you do want to access those fns?

Comment: What actually means "access" to these functions? does it mean being able to arbitrarily call them from anywhere, or that the saved network uses it and therefore won't be able to run at all?

Comment: This answer does not contain a solution to the problem. The warning may mean that the saved model cannot be reloaded in the future like @FlorianLalande explained - his answer should be upvoted.

Comment: @mac13k His answer is not providing a solution either.

Comment: @Scholar- fair point, but at least the explanation is quite thorough.

Answer (score 11):

### If you ignore this warning, you will not be able to reload your model.

What this warning is telling you is that you are using customized layers and losses in your model architecture.

The `ModelCheckpoint` callback saves your model after each epoch with a lower validation loss achieved. Models can be saved in HDF5 format or SavedModel format (default, specific to TensorFlow and Keras). You are using the SavedModel format here, as you didn't explicitly specify the `.h5` extension.

Every time a new epoch reaches a lower validation loss, you model is automatically saved, but your customized objects (layers and losses) are not traced. Btw, this is why the warning is only prompted after several training epochs.

Without your traced customized objects, you will not be able to reload your model successfully with `keras.models.load_model()`.

If you do not intent to reload your best model in the future, you can safely ignore this warning. In any case, you can still use your best model in your current local environment after training.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mind sharing a solution to the problem? As it stands, this has been an old issue in Tensorflow (yet to be fix), with the majority of people having no issues running the loaded model.

Comment: This is not true, this warning also comes up with standard TF layers and the model can be safely saved and reload.

Comment: I can also confirm that this is not true - the model loads just fine

Comment: Where is the customized object of his model?

Answer (score 9):

saving models in H5 format seems to work for me.

```
model.save(filepath, save_format="h5")
```

Here is how to use H5 with model checkpointing (I've not tested this extensively, caveat emptor!)

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

class ModelCheckpointH5(ModelCheckpoint):
    # There is a bug saving models in TF 2.4
    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47479
    # This forces the h5 format for saving
    def __init__(self,
               filepath,
               monitor='val_loss',
               verbose=0,
               save_best_only=False,
               save_weights_only=False,
               mode='auto',
               save_freq='epoch',
               options=None,
               **kwargs):
        super(ModelCheckpointH5, self).__init__(filepath,
               monitor='val_loss',
               verbose=0,
               save_best_only=False,
               save_weights_only=False,
               mode='auto',
               save_freq='epoch',
               options=None,
               **kwargs)
    def _save_model(self, epoch, logs):
        from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
   
        logs = logs or {}

        if isinstance(self.save_freq,
                      int) or self.epochs_since_last_save >= self.period:
          # Block only when saving interval is reached.
          logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
          self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
          filepath = self._get_file_path(epoch, logs)

          try:
            if self.save_best_only:
              current = logs.get(self.monitor)
              if current is None:
                logging.warning('Can save best model only with %s available, '
                                'skipping.', self.monitor)
              else:
                if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
                  if self.verbose > 0:
                    print('\nEpoch %05d: %s improved from %0.5f to %0.5f,'
                          ' saving model to %s' % (epoch + 1, self.monitor,
                                                   self.best, current, filepath))
                  self.best = current
                  if self.save_weights_only:
                    self.model.save_weights(
                        filepath, overwrite=True, options=self._options)
                  else:
                    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True, options=self._options,save_format="h5") # NK edited here
                else:
                  if self.verbose > 0:
                    print('\nEpoch %05d: %s did not improve from %0.5f' %
                          (epoch + 1, self.monitor, self.best))
            else:
              if self.verbose > 0:
                print('\nEpoch %05d: saving model to %s' % (epoch + 1, filepath))
              if self.save_weights_only:
                self.model.save_weights(
                    filepath, overwrite=True, options=self._options)
              else:
                self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True, options=self._options,save_format="h5") # NK edited here

            self._maybe_remove_file()
          except IOError as e:
            # `e.errno` appears to be `None` so checking the content of `e.args[0]`.
            if 'is a directory' in six.ensure_str(e.args[0]).lower():
              raise IOError('Please specify a non-directory filepath for '
                            'ModelCheckpoint. Filepath used is an existing '
                            'directory: {}'.format(filepath))
            # Re-throw the error for any other causes.
            raise
```

Answer (score 3):

Try appending the extension to the file.

```
save_weights_at = 'basic_lstm_model'
```

For:

```
save_weights_at = 'basic_lstm_model.h5'
```

Answer (score -1):

save the model in .tf format if there is issue in saving the model

```
model.save('you_model_name.tf')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think @Florian Lalande is right and this warning should not be ignored.
Here is my solution that not sure can work.

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, save_model_path) # save as savemodel form
test_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(save_model_path, custom_objects={"TFBertModel": transformers.TFBertModel}) # load model and point out the custom_objects
```

The idea is to use tf.keras.models.load_model with custom_objects.

Comment: there is no custom objct in the original post