# how to save and load custom siamese bert model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I am following this tutorial on how to train a siamese bert network:

https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/

all good, but I am not sure what is the best way to save the model after train it and save it.
any suggestion?

I was trying with

`model.save('models/bert_siamese_v1')`

which creates a folder with save_model.bp keras_metadata.bp and two subfolders (variables and assets)

then I try to load it with:

```
model.load_weights('models/bert_siamese_v1/')
```

and it gives me this error:

```
2022-03-08 14:11:52.567762: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open models/bert_siamese_v1/: Failed precondition: models/bert_siamese_v1; Is a directory: perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Maybe `new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('models/bert_siamese_v1/')`

Comment: it gives me 'ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `tf.saved_model.save` to save your model:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'models/bert_siamese_v1')
model = tf.saved_model.load('models/bert_siamese_v1')
```

The warning you get during saving can [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697623/tensorflow-warning-found-untraced-functions-such-as-lstm-cell-6-layer-call-and) be ignored. After loading your model, you can use it for inference `f(test_data)`:

```
f = model.signatures["serving_default"]
x1 = tf.random.uniform((1, 128), maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)
x2 = tf.random.uniform((1, 128), maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)
x3 = tf.random.uniform((1, 128), maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)
print(f)
print(f(attention_masks = x1, input_ids = x2, token_type_ids = x3))
```

```
ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(*, token_type_ids, attention_masks, input_ids)
  Args:
    attention_masks: int32 Tensor, shape=(None, 128)
    input_ids: int32 Tensor, shape=(None, 128)
    token_type_ids: int32 Tensor, shape=(None, 128)
  Returns:
    {'dense': <1>}
      <1>: float32 Tensor, shape=(None, 3)
{'dense': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.40711606, 0.13456087, 0.45832306]], dtype=float32)>}
```

Comment: I tried it and it lets me save and load giving e all the warning you mentioned, but seems that now the predict function doesn't work anymore:  AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict' (when running model.predict() with the correct inputs which were working

Comment: can you try running `model(test_data)` instead of `model.predict(test_data)`? Since the `SavedModel` object is not a `Keras` object. Also check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755970/how-to-load-a-model-with-tf-saved-model-and-call-the-predict-function-tensorflo

Comment: I tried and it gives me a new error! ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total): etc....

Comment: so I tried using the info you provided in based on f:  input_ids , attention_masks ,token_type_ids = test_data.__getitem__(0) then i run  proba = model1(attention_masks, input_ids, token_type_ids) but the error still stands: ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=int32)
    * Tensor("training:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=int32)
    * Tensor("mask:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=int32)
  Keyword arguments: {}

Comment: Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * [TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_masks'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='token_type_ids')]
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Comment: Did you check my updated answer? There I am showing you how to feed arguments to your model...It works without any problems. You just have to use the input names: `attention_masks`, `input_ids`, and `token_type_ids`. I am using the exact same model that you linked.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have two options

- [manually save weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#manually_save_weights)

```
 model.save_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')
   
 model = create_model()
   
 model.load_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')
```

- save the [entire model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model)

Call model.save to save a model's architecture, weights, and training configuration in a single file/folder. This allows you to export a model so it can be used without access to the original Python code*. Since the optimizer-state is recovered, you can resume training from exactly where you left off.

Save model

```
# Create and train a new model instance.
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

# Save the entire model as a SavedModel.
!mkdir -p saved_model
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
```

load model

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
```

It seems that you are mixing both approaches, saving model and loading weights.